# Не извлекаются все документы из смешанного списка Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

занялся вопросом парсинга многоуровневого сайта. С помощью bs4 собрал список ссылок находящихся на сайте под тегом `<a>`, получил некий смешанный список. Решил создать функцию для сортировки и разделения этого смешанного списка на 2 отдельных (список с ссылками на страницы и список с ссылками на файлы).

```
list_fuze =['http://www.npi-tu.ru/assets/files/2019/04/26/polozhenie_skan.PDF',
            'http://www.npi-tu.ru/assets/files/docs/of_docs/2014/Polozhenie-ob-obrabotke-PDn-rabotnikov.doc',
            'http://www.npi-tu.ru/assets/files/docs/of_docs/2014/Sbornik-instrukcij_PD.docx',
            'http://www.npi-tu.ru/assets/files/docs/of_docs/2018/09/obrazec-ekspertnyh-zaklyuchenij.docx',
            'http://www.nica.ru/media/default/documents/postanovlenie_1039.pdf',
            'http://www.npi-tu.ru/assets/files/education/university/regulations/local/organization/poryadok-organizacii-i-osushhestvleniya-od-po-op-vo.pdf',
            'http://www.npi-tu.ru/assets/files/2019/10/polozhenie-cdodv-novoe.pdf',
            'http://media.npi-tu.ru',
            'https://vk.com/club_npi']

def pars_sort(list_arg):
    list_doc = list()
    list_links = list_arg
    for link in list_arg:
        if link.endswith(('PDF', 'pdf', 'doc', 'dox', 'docx')):
            list_links.remove(link)
            list_doc.append(link)
        else:
            continue
    print ('Список документов:',list_doc)
    print ('Список ссылок',list_links)

pars_sort(list_fuze)
```

Но в результате из смешанного списка извлекаются не все сслыки заканчивающиеся на  указанный список "окончаний". И я не могу понять почему некоторые ссылки с окончанием .pdf извлеклись, а некоторые нет.  Так же пробовал сделать множества вместо ссылок, но происходит таймаут итерации. Подскажите пожалуйста почему так. Прошу быть снисходительным , первые шаги в изучении программирования.

Comment: 1) `for link in set_fuze:` и `set_fuze.remove(link)` очень плохая идея удаления элементов из списка во время перебора элементов списка. Это как у машины на ходу начать замену всех колес 2) Добавьте в вопрос пример тех ссылок из list_fuze, т.е. в вопросе нужен [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы любой мог запустить и убедиться что ссылка с `7new.pdf'` не попадает в результат, хотя по коду должна

Comment: def pars_sort(list_fuze): не должен ли аргумент быть   set_fuze ?

Comment: @splash58 прошу прощения, это осталось после экспериментов с множествами. Обращается он к аргументу верно.

Comment: @gil9red добавил примеры, и 1-вый совет учту, действительно, не подумал об этом

Comment: @gil9red вроде бы теперь код похож на  минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно разделить списки за один проход и без использования функции:

```
list_doc = []
list_links = []
_ = [list_doc.append(x) if x.lower().endswith(('pdf', 'doc', 'dox', 'docx')) 
                        else list_links.append(x) 
     for x in list_fuze]
```

или в виде функции:

```
def split_urls(urls, doc_ext=('pdf', 'doc', 'dox', 'docx')):
    list_doc = []
    list_links = []
    _ = [list_doc.append(x) if x.lower().endswith(doc_ext) 
                            else list_links.append(x) 
         for x in list_fuze]
    return list_doc, list_links

list_doc, list_links = split_urls(list_fuze)
```

---

Результат:

```
In [8]: list_doc
Out[8]:
['http://www.npi-tu.ru/assets/files/2019/04/26/polozhenie_skan.PDF',
 'http://www.npi-tu.ru/assets/files/docs/of_docs/2014/Polozhenie-ob-obrabotke-PDn-rabotnikov.doc',
 'http://www.npi-tu.ru/assets/files/docs/of_docs/2014/Sbornik-instrukcij_PD.docx',
 'http://www.npi-tu.ru/assets/files/docs/of_docs/2018/09/obrazec-ekspertnyh-zaklyuchenij.docx',
 'http://www.nica.ru/media/default/documents/postanovlenie_1039.pdf',
 'http://www.npi-tu.ru/assets/files/education/university/regulations/local/organization/poryadok-organizacii-i-osushhestvleniya-od-po-op-vo.pdf',
 'http://www.npi-tu.ru/assets/files/2019/10/polozhenie-cdodv-novoe.pdf']

In [9]: list_links
Out[9]: ['http://media.npi-tu.ru', 'https://vk.com/club_npi']
```

Comment: Спасибо большое ! Теперь буду разбираться с вашим способом решения этой проблемы ) потому что некоторые методы в коде:
' _ = [list_doc.append(x) if x.lower().endswith(doc_ext) 
                            else list_links.append(x) ' 
вижу первый раз ) Очень познавательно )